# What is the best approach to create reducers and actions in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I was creating the structure of the redux action and reducer but got stuck on some points. Please have a look at the below example:

- I have one page, In which I'm displaying the categories list. In the same page, we have add and remove the category button. I have created one reducer `category` which have the following states:

  initial states = {isLoading: false, error: '', categories}

and have some actions like categoryFetchStart,categoryFetchSuccess and categoryFetchFailure.
I'm calling respective actions for displaying the category data and error messages.

Now, as I mentioned above, we also have 'add New Category' and 'Delete category' button. I think we should not handle these cases in the same reducers, otherwise it would rerender the whole categories list.

So for these operations, Do I need to make separate reducers and actions? because isLoading state of these operations should not be connected otherwise it may rerender the categories list.
Please let me know what is the best approach to handle these cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can create different action but no need for different reducer because you can connect list with just that state which is needed in that component.

Comment: But what about the separate loader for add category action? Suppose I have a modal popup with `create category` button. When user clicks on this button, I need to display the loader just near the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/quick-start) it’s the best solution if you’re new to redux. Also it runs [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) under the hood which means that you can write mutable code inside your reducers which otherwise can get very verbose for instance you may have to write a one page reducer just to toggle a nested property